# PHPexcel with Phpmailer

Tags: php, phpmailer, phpexcel

Is use the following code to generate a excel file, attach it and sent it as email. But when I opening the Excel file in my inbox Excel says that the file could be damaged or it unsafe. I can open the file if I click yes and it shows the data file but I would like to remove the warning message.

```
[CODE HERE]    
//Generating Excel data

$objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($objPHPExcel);
$objWriter->save("php://output");

$data = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->addAddress('mail@mail.com');

$mail->AddStringAttachment($data, '123.xls')
$mail->isHTML(true);     

$mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
$mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';

if(!$mail->Send()) {
echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
echo "Message sent!";
}
```

Comment: Almost all mail client consider attachments as "unsafe" and will issue a message about it. This is especially true for attachments which may have executable code in them (Excel files fall into that category because they may contain macros). As the sender of the file you do not have any control over whether or not a message like that is displayed on the receiving end.

Comment: But I save it locally first from the mail client and then opening it

Comment: Ah, that bit wasn't clear. You said you were opening it in your inbox not after saving it. If you save the spreadsheet you are generating and attach it using $mail->AddAttachment do you have the same problem?

Comment: When I save it to the webserver I get error 500.

Comment: And when that happens what does the error log say? Saving it to disk before attaching would not, alone, result in an error.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps you may have a partially output in `[CODE HERE]` and written that to the Excel.